# PHP Smooth and Dynamic Pagination,Paginator

Tags: php, pagination, paging, paginator

How make this pagination smooth & dynamic (Slike xenforo forum) ?
Ex:
1condition: 1 23456 -> 99

When click ->
2: condition 1 <- 7891011 ->99

For example if click "->" many times it will be updated at once.

Comment: Look up "php mysql pagination" on the web.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! SO is **not** a *free* coding service. Learn [ask] before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].